# What is the difference between textView and TextView

Tags: android

When I use the code :

```
t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

I get the error :

```
textView cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

And it shows fix like *change to TextView*, but they are still not working after changing `id` to `textView`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Without the layout XML file, it's almost impossible to know the source of the problem. Please post your XML file.

Comment: Do read developer.android.com

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `TextView` in your layout xml file with the `android:id="+@id/textview"` try changing the `android:id="+@id/textview"` to something else eg: `android:id="+@id/mytextview"`

Then try adding the following code to the java file:

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
```

Also try cleaning your project once

Answer (score 0):

`textView` is the id you specify in the xml

and `TextView` is a View(like Button)

Solution:

Make sure that you an id `textView` in xml

.. Post your xml

Answer (score 0):

`TextView` is the View which is the Reserved Word in `ADT` whereas `textView` is the name you have specified in the Xml under `TextView` tag.

For e.g.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

By below line

```
 TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

you are setting this id `textView` to `TextView s` object `t`

save and clean rebuild. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

TextView (with capital T)is the reserved word in ADT and textview(with small letter t) is the id you specify for the view.
Just have a look:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"    // the id you give
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10sp"/>
```

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

Words starting with capital letter like `EditText`, `TextView` etc are reserved words else are the id's one uses for initialization in an activity...